# Python shorthand exception handling

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

There's a certain problem I've been having with exception handling in Python.  There have been many situations where there is an area of code where I want all exceptions to be ignored.  Say I have 100 lines of code where I want this to happen.

This is what most would think would be the solution:

```
try:
    line 1
    line 2
    line 3
    ...
    line 99
    line 100
except:
    pass
```

This actually does not work in my situation (and many other situations).  Assume line 3 has an exception.  Once the exception is thrown, it goes straight to "pass", and skips lines 4-100.  The only solution I've been able to come up with is this:

```
try:
    line 1
except:
    pass

try:
    line 2
except:
    pass

try:
    line 3
except:
    pass

...

try:
    line 99
except:
    pass

try:
    line 100
except:
    pass
```

But, as is obvious, this is extremely ugly, sloppy, and takes absolutely forever.  How can I do the above code in a shorter, cleaner way?  Bonus points if you give a method that allows "pass" to be replaced with other code.

Comment: It sounds like you need to do some serious re-design of your code. Do you really have 100 completely independent lines of code that don't depend on each other at all, and can't be placed in a loop, that all might fail in ways your code can recover from?

Comment: if you are doing tests, you should really have incremental tests anyways... So for example.... if the work flow is a->b->c, to do c, it needs to do a->b first.... so if a or b fail, there would be no reason to test for c.

Comment: I don't actually have 100 lines, I sometimes have 6 or 7, though.  Even with just 6 or 7, it is still very sloppy.

Comment: Yes, in good code you should only catch exceptions that you somehow expect which means you should for sure specify the exception you want to catch. It would be a very, very bad idea to catch exceptions in a way that your bad code would work. Catch things e.g. transforming a string into an integer but the string cannot converted because it does not represent a number.

Comment: But, again, are those really completely independent? As in, if any one of them fails, your program is completely okay? And can you not put them in a loop?

Comment: @ Morgan - Yes and no.  They do depend on each other, but they still work if one of them fails.  I cannot put them in a loop, they are completely different.

Comment: Well, there are also times where they are independent.  I've needed to do this in many circumstances.

Comment: Normally I'd give some specific examples, but I'm dealing with some code I've made that is over 12,000 lines of code, and I wouldn't want to have to explain it all, or give up all my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other answers have already stated, you should consider refactoring your code.

That said, I couldn't resist not hacking something together to be able to execute your function without failing and breaking out in case an exception occurs.

```
import ast, _ast, compiler

def fail():
    print "Hello, World!"
    raise Exception
    x = [4, 5]
    print x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(__file__, 'r') as source:
        tree = ast.parse(source.read(), __file__)
        for node in ast.iter_child_nodes(tree):
            if isinstance(node, _ast.FunctionDef):
                _locals = {}
                for line in node.body:
                    mod = ast.Module()
                    mod.body = [line]
                    try:
                        exec(compile(mod, filename='<ast>', mode='exec'), _locals, globals())
                    except:
                        import traceback
                        traceback.print_exc()
```

The code executes any function it finds in global scope, and prevents it from exiting in the event it fails. It does so by iterating over the AST of the file, and creating a new module to execute for each line of the the function.

As you would expect, the output of the program is:

```
Hello, World!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kek.py", line 18, in <module>
    exec(compile(m, filename='<ast>', mode='exec'), _locals, globals())
  File "<ast>", line 3, in <module>
Exception
[4, 5]
```

I should emphasize that using this in any production code is a **bad idea**. But for the sake of argument, something like this would work. You could even wrap it in a nice decorator, though that wouldn't do anything to the fact that it's a **bad idea**.

Happy refactoring!

Comment: While it isn't the answer I'd like, it does still answer my question.  I'll probably just stick to the old way (it's really just a few lines of code, not 100), because this is production code.  My entire code isn't sloppy like this, but there are some places where things get super complicated and messy.

Answer (score 0):

You could try breaking the code into smaller chunks so that it can properly handle errors instead of needing to abandon all progress and loop back through.

Another solution that can be used in addition to that is making checks, if set flags for your code to check if it can proceed or if it needs to repeat the last step you would be able to prevent extra iterations.

Example:

```
while not continue:
    try:
        a = input('Enter data')
    except:
        pass
    if a != null:
        continue = true
```